# DSM to DTM limited by polygon

Tags: qgis, dem, filtering

I am currently struggling with a specific DSM to DTM conversion requirement over a raster dataset in QGIS. DSM was born from photogrammetry and I need to automatically get rid of houses and vegetation.

I am aware of the DTM Filter (slope based) plugins/algorithms - both native QGIS and SAGA and these work well, but always over the entire raster. I would need to use this filter only over part of the grid. Example (with picture):

1. I need to filter out these building features
2. I need to preserve these erosion depressions
   [image]

Is there a specific procedure for this in QGIS? If not, recommendations for other software?

Comment: Could you clip the DSM to the area you want to filter, perform the DTM calculation, and then burn the result back into the original DSM?

Comment: Thanks, @Matt, it seems to me the only option... or remove DMS within polygons of recent features and fill the holes then...